# Document handling 3rd party server

Tags: google-drive-api, document-management

I need to upload my files(documents,images,videos) to a 3rd party server using my own application and need to retrieve them. But there should be a way to give access levels to files. I checked google drive supporting this.But they have no option to give my application's user level access to files. They are giving user level access with google accounts. I need set my user account access to files.

Please advice me if there is anyway to do this.

Comment: you need to insert the permissions to the file https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions its based upon a user gmail.  Unless you are using a service account your application isn't a user.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for the quick response